# pass value in function cakephp 2

Tags: php, cakephp

i have function which culullate average rate of the teacher and i save the average on the variable `$result` i want pass the variable to the `get_teacher_average_rating` and print the average , but i try do that i have error

> Notice (8): Undefined variable: result
>   [APP/Controller/RatingSchoolsController.php, line 30] Warning (2):
>   Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output
>   started at
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/classera-core-code/lib/Cake/Utility/Debugger.php:795)
>   [APP/Controller/AppController.php, line 67]

how can i fix that and print average in `get_teacher_average_rating`

```
public function set_teacher_average_rating($result)
    {
        $this->autoRender = false;
        if($this->request->is('get'))
        {
            $author_id = $this->request->query('author_id');//
            $rate = $this->Rating->find('all',array('conditions'=>array('author_id'=> $author_id), 'fields'=> array('AVG(Rating.value) as averageRating'), 'recursive' =>-1));

            $average = $rate[0][0]['averageRating'];
            $result = array('success'=>'1' , 'average' => $average );
        }
        else{
            $result = array('success'=>'0','message'=>'request type is not GET');
        }
        echo json_encode($result);
    }


public function get_teacher_average_rating()
    {
        $this->autoRender = false;
                $average = $this->set_teacher_average_rating($result);
                $rate = $this->Rating->find('all',array('conditions'=>array('author_id'=> $author_id)));

                     //get rate teacher
                                echo json_encode($average);



        }
```

Comment: `$average = $this->get_teacher_average_rating($result);` __What__ is `$result` here?

Comment: where does $result come from in get_teacher_average_rating? from the View? Session ?

Comment: So `get_teacher_average_rating` calls `get_teacher_average_rating`? Are you sure you doing it right?

Comment: @u_mulder sorry i edit my cod get_teacher_average_rating calls set_teacher_average_rating

Comment: @u_mulder i want pass $result from method set_teacher_average_rating and print this value in method get_teacher_average_rating can you help me

Comment: @SirGalahad i want pass $result from method set_teacher_average_rating and print this value in method get_teacher_average_rating can you help me

Answer (score 0):

try this if the function set_teacher_average_rating() is not called by any other function :

```
public function set_teacher_average_rating()
    {
        $this->autoRender = false;
        if($this->request->is('get'))
        {
            $author_id = $this->request->query('author_id');//
            $rate = $this->Rating->find('all',array('conditions'=>array('author_id'=> $author_id), 'fields'=> array('AVG(Rating.value) as averageRating'), 'recursive' =>-1));

            $average = $rate[0][0]['averageRating'];
            $result = array('success'=>'1' , 'average' => $average );
        }
        else{
            $result = array('success'=>'0','message'=>'request type is not GET');
        }
        return $result;
    }


public function get_teacher_average_rating()
    {
        $this->autoRender = false;
                $average = $this->set_teacher_average_rating();
                $rate = $this->Rating->find('all',array('conditions'=>array('author_id'=> $author_id)));

                     //get rate teacher
                                echo json_encode($average);



        }
```

Comment: i try your code but display error message "Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted"

Comment: then fixed this error .there are many examples  to fixed this error on internet